# How to read JUST filenames of a directory in python and then do the same job for all?

Tags: python, string, numpy, replace, readfile

I have a python script which has this line at the very beginning to read from an input data file:

```
    x,y = genfromtxt('data1.txt').T
```

Then I proceed and do the processing on x,y (it depends on a fixed parameter e.g n=5). Finally I generate the output file with this line

```
    with open('output_data1_n{0}.txt'.format(num),'wb') as file:
```

This gives me output_data1_n5.txt and write the xnew and ynew on it.

Question: I have a directory with many txt files! How can I systematically do this job for all files in that directory instead of running by hand for each input file?

It should be like: get the txt files (e.g with os.walk ?) as a string and replace it to input, then generate the output name including the parameter n.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: did you try os.walk ?

Comment: I did, but I got just the file names, but was not able to pass them as input file and then makes the output name!

Comment: instead of 'data1.txt', just put the result from os.walk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Inbar Rose has already explained, you can get the list of files using `glob`. To convert the input filenames into appropriate output filenames, you could use a regex to extract the file number from the input name, and then use that to construct the output name.

Something like this:

```
import os
import glob
import re

inputPath = '.' # the directory where your files are stored
num = 5         # the fixed parameter, n

# first obtain all the data*.txt files in the directory
for inputName in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputPath,'data*.txt')):

  # attempt to extract the file number from the input name
  fileNum = re.findall(r'data([0-9]+)\.txt',inputName)
  # if not successful, skip this file
  if not fileNum: continue

  # create the output filename using the fle number and the fixed parameter
  outputName = 'output_data{0}_{1}.txt'.format(fileNum[0],num)
  # add the input path to the filename, or use a different path if necessary
  outputName = os.path.join(inputPath,outputName)

  # process the file
  x,y = genfromtxt(inputName).T
  with open(outputName,'wb') as file: 
    # do the rest of your code here
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I am sure it is close to what I want, just gives me an error that                                                                                                                                     outputName = 'output_data{0}_{1}.dat'.format(fileNum[0],num)
NameError: name 'fileNum' is not defined

Comment: I suspect you may have mistyped something when copying my answer, or perhaps changed the indentation in a way that broke the code. I've just cut and paste that code into a file to test, and other than needing to comment out the `genfromtxt` line, it works perfectly.

Comment: I did the same to test. It does not give me that error anymore, but does not produce anything also. The script runs but no output. I guess I do not get the input names, because when I try to check the names by putting this command:"for i in range(0,1): print fileNum[i]" right before the line with outputName..., it gives me error. How can I print out the filenames to be sure? I am very new to python, sorry

Comment: I would add `print inputName` on the first line of the for loop to make sure it is finding files. Then a `print outpuName` the line after it has generated the `outputName` to see what it has generated. And if you want to see the file number, `print fileNum[0]` - it's a single item array. I'm assuming you've filled in the `inputPath` variable with something meaningful? And that your input files really are of the form `data1.txt`, `data2.txt`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot James for your patince! the key was that I had 3 digits number and "K" in file extension so I had to specify the data as [0-999]+K. All works now. cheers

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you got it working. Although I would appreciate an upvote on the answer if you have enough rep. :)

Comment: I didnt know about it. But seems that I dont have enough to vote up

Comment: Strange. Should just require 15 rep. But it's not a big deal, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

It lets you get a list of file names in a directory with some wild cards.

Example:

```
from glob import glob
from os import path

def get_files_in(folder, pattern='*.txt'):
    return glob(path.join(folder, pattern))
```

Usage:

```
get_files_in('C:/temp') # files in C:/temp that are ending with .txt
get_files_in('C:/temp', '*.xml') # files in C:/temp that are ending with .xml
get_files_in('C:/temp', 'test_*.csv') # files in C:/temp that start with test_ and end in .csv
```